# What is the different between assignment and parameter passing?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I can assign a sequence like this in python:

```
a,b,c="ABC"
```

But I am unable to pass this sequence to a function as a parameter. i.e

```
def function2(a,b,c):
    print a
    print b
    print c
function2("ABC")
```

The above statement is raising an error.

Can any one tell me the difference between assignment and argument passing in python?

Comment: your function has 3 parameters defined, but when you call it, you're only passing in ONE argument, so `ABC` gets assigned to `a` in the function, and b,c are left undefined.

Comment: For fun, try `function2(*"ABC")`

Answer (score 9):

The compiler sees a comma-separated list on the LHS and emits bytecode to iterate over the RHS for you. With the function call it sees a single value and so sends it as a single argument. You need to tell it to split the sequence explicitly:

```
>>> function2(*"ABC")
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you created takes 3 parameters a, b, and c. But when you're calling the function you only provide one parameter.

To correctly call your function, you would need to do something like

```
function2("A","B","C")
```

and it would print
    A
    B
    C

Answer (score 0):

Functions can have optional parameters, specified as parameters with default argument values. Consider the function

```
def function2(a, b=None, c=None):
   print a
   print b
   print c
```

Which of the following should `function2("ABC")` output?

```
ABC
None
None
```

or

```
A
B
C
```

Python opts for the first choice, instead of examining whether some of the parameters have default values, where an iterable value is treated as a single value for argument passing, and the special syntax

```
function2(*"ABC")
```

provides the second.

Comment: I think you mean "Python opts for the first choice".

Comment: I originally had the two choices reversed, and forgot to update that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one's mentioned this yet, the `a, b, c = "ABC"` assigns a = "A", b = "B" and c = "C" as a string also functions as an iterator of sorts, that is, you can loop over it, check for characters in it just like checking elements of a list etc etc.

It's similar to the code

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

Python interprets that as

```
(a, b) = (1, 2)
```

and the compiler detects 2 variables and so makes 2 assignments. When you pass 3 to a length 3 string, it works the same:

```
(a, b, c) = ("A", "B", "C")
```

However, as the others have said, in a function parameter passing, `function2(a, b, c)` must take 3 arguments, and "ABC" is only one object: a string, and so assigns `a = "ABC"` and then raises and error on `b` and `c`. To get the same behavior as `a, b, c = ("A", "B", "C")`, you parse it with a `*`, that is

```
function2(*"ABC") # is the same as function2("A", "B", "C")
```

The `*` parser works for any iterable: lists, (strings), dict (keys) etc